# How to insert Exchange Rate Types record with suitescript in netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suite

I want to create new records for exchange rate types, but after I searched for it I just found to do it via CSV import.

How can I insert records in suitescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this record is not yet exposed in Suite Script, you can not create an Exchange Rate Record through Suite Script directly.

NetSuite offers three ways to update the Currency Exchange Rates :

Manually via the menu Lists --> Accounting --> Currency Exchange Rates.

Via CSV Import.

Via Web Services (NetSuite’s SuiteTalk).

For more info please check this link out :

http://blog.prolecto.com/2013/05/30/updating-netsuites-currency-rates-programmatically/